# Converting geotiff from geographic coordinates to UTM_WGS84 using Python?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp, utm

Does anyone know how to quickly convert a number of geotiff images with geographic coordinate systems (GCS_WGS84) to UTM_WGS84? Preferably using python.

I tried gdalwarp below but it failed:
[image]

The spatial reference of the source image is shown below:
[image]

Comment: which UTM zone do you want? UTM on it's own is not a projection

Comment: I have a few different regions. Let's say Zone 4

Comment: Try to enclose proj4 string between double quotes. But check first that your string is correct. And it would easier to use the EPSG codes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also I'm new to this. Can you be more specific about how to use the EPSG codes?

Comment: Please always include commands and output as text rather than pictures so that they are available to future searches.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that UTM is not a projection that PROJ.4 can recognise, you need to add the zone number and hemisphere.

So if you want [Zone 4N in proj.4](http://epsg.io/32604.proj4) style it is

```
 +proj=utm +zone=4 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

or the more succinct [EPSG](http://epsg.io/32604) form is:

```
 EPSG:32604
```

Comment: I suppose that the syntax that is copied from the documentation http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html is ok but single quotes work only on Linux. On Windows double quotes are required. Zone was included in the original command but screen capture cuts it on two rows.

Comment: You were right. Double quotes works!!!

Comment: Thanks for reply, Ian. I also have a few shapefiles that I wanted to convert to UTM. It seems that gdalwarp doesn't work for shapefiles. Do you have some other solutions for this?

Comment: http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html